# How do I measure the SOAP processing time of a JAX-WS WebMethod?

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jamon

Interface:

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;

@WebService(name="Webservice")
public interface IWebservice{
    @WebMethod
    public Collection<SomeValue> doSthg();
}
```

I would like to measure the time, how long it takes JavaWS to serialize the returned `Collection<SomeValue>` in to SOAP. I have tried it with Jamon, but becauee SOAP is somehow generated in the background I can't find a way to instrumentate the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SOAPUI.  You can get very accurate timings of your send and receive:

http://www.soapui.org/

SoapUI is also invaluable for testing and debugging.

IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [jProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html). It provides a Call Tree.

edit: ... and SOAPUI.